# Convert JSON string to function parameters

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, arguments

I have a string of javascript objects that I need to convert to function arguments.

The string looks like this:

```
"{ "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 1" }, { "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 2" }"
```

I can concat "[ ]" and call JSON.parse to turn it into a valid array however, this does not solve my problem since the function needs them to be separate objects not an array of objects.

EX:

```
functionCall({ "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 1" }, { "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 2" });
```

I will never know how many objects will be in this string so I do not know how many arguments the function should accept either.

I would love to be able to add multiple objects to one variable like:

```
var objects = { "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 1" }, { "item1": "foo 1", "item2": "bar 2" }
```

and then I could just call

```
functionCall(objects);
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like this or another approach I can take?

Comment: I believe you want `functionCall.apply(null, objects)` but the `objects` must be an array for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**:

```
functionCall.apply(window, objects);
```

(Replace `window` with whatever scope you'd like the function to have.)

The second argument is an array of objects, so go ahead and put the objects in an array and then use `apply`.

Comment: Just realized you answered this I guess a split second sooner... Thank you also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to convert an array into function arguments:

```
functionCall.apply(null, objects);
```

The initial `null` argument is the `this` argument for the function; if you're not calling an object method, it's not needed and `null` can be used as a placeholder.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! For some reason I expected that to return it as an array not as separate objects. I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer but I will. Thanks again.

Comment: That's what happens if you just call the function normally. The whole point of `.apply` is to spread the array.